# How to get all .c files and store into a variable in a makefile

Tags: make

I am writing inside a `Makefile` and inside this current directory is a folder called `files` with a lot of `.c` files.

I need to get all these `.c` files and store it into a variable called `SOURCES`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 5):

If you can expect your `Makefile` to be used with GNU Make, you can use its [`wildcard` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html):

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard files/*.c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(shell ...)` to put the result of a command into a make variable.

```
SOURCES = $(shell ls files/*.c)

show:
    echo $(SOURCES)
```

Comment: Would this not have the same issues as when parsing the output of `ls` in the shell, i.e., that files with whitespace characters would be split into multiple entries in the resulting list?

Comment: @Kusalananda Probably. I've never attempted to use make with files that have whitespace so I don't have much experience with it.

Comment: @Kusalananda Make doesn’t deal with file names containing whitespace in general; using the external `ls` command or the built-in `wildcard` function doesn’t make any difference in this respect.

Comment: @StephenKitt Ah, so it breaks even when you're using `wildcard`. Ok.